# Computing an orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra

In $R^3$, find an orthonormal basis for the subspace $[span ((1,1,1))]^\perp$.

I just want to make sure that my answer is right.

Let $V$ be a subspace of $R^3$ spanned by $(1,1,1)^\perp$. Then, $||v||$ = $\sqrt3$.
The basis $e = {v\over ||v||}$ = $1\over \sqrt 3 (1,1,1)$. Is it correct? I am confused by $[span ((1,1,1))]^\perp$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Note that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{(1,1,1)\}^\bot=\bigl\{\vec x\in\Bbb R^3:\bigl\langle\vec x,(1,1,1)\bigr\rangle=0\bigr\}
$$
Thus $\vec x\in\Span\{(1,1,1)\}^\bot$ if and only if 
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3=0
$$
That is, $\vec x\in\Span\{(1,1,1)\}^\bot$ if and only if 
$$
\vec x
=(x_1,x_2,x_3)
=(x_1,x_2,-x_1-x_2)
=x_1\cdot (1,0,-1)+x_2\cdot(0,1,-1)
$$
This implies that $\bigl\{(1,0,-1),(0,1,-1)\bigr\}$ is a basis for $\Span\{(1,1,1)\}^\bot$. Do you know of any [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) whose input is a basis and whose output is an orthonormal basis?

Comment: Not really and how did you get $x_3=-x_1-x_2$ ? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If $x_1+x_2+x_3=0$, then what is $x_3$?

Comment: got it! x_3 = -x_2 -x_1. I guess you use standard basis for $x_1,x_2,x_3$ and then you got a basis for $span{1,1,1}^\perp$. Then, I guess I have to find orthonormal basis by using GS process. Thanks! I am still confused with $span{1,1,1}^\perp$. Thanks for the hints!